# "Lasciarsi con qualcuno". È corretto?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

"*[Lasciare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lasciare/)*" è verbo transitivo, quindi tipicamente "*A lascia B*". Ma è anche riflessivo reciproco: "*A e B si lasciano*".

Ma si può esprimere quest'ultima frase dal punto di vista del solo B? Usando un semplice riflessivo: "*B si lascia con A*"?

Certamente è diffuso a livello colloquiale: mi chiedevo quanto sia accettabile in forma scritta o formale.

Comment: Mi viene anche in mente una frase del tipo: _le parti si sono lasciate con un accordo_.

Comment: Che però è del caso riflessivo reciproco: le parti si sono lasciate tra di loro, e "con un accordo" è solo compl. di mezzo

Comment: In all examples from GoogleBooks there is no usage instance of “lasciarsi con” referring to the person involved but rather  the way or the means by which it happened. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lasciarsi+con%22&lr=lang_it&safe=strict&tbs=lr:lang_1it&tbm=bks&prmd=nvi&ei=1mWTXdTvIMLdwQLqmKmoCA&start=30&sa=N&biw=768&bih=984&dpr=2

Comment: @Gio: Non sono sicuro di che cosa stai vedendo; forse Google Books mostra risultati diversi a persone diverse. Limitando la ricerca al 21° secolo, trovo frasi come “Silvana Mangano doveva lasciarsi con il suo amante”, “Più di un ragazzo mi ha detto che lasciarsi con me significava...”, “Martina Stella, prima di lasciarsi con Lapo Elkann...”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

È difficile dare una risposta conclusiva ma ritengo significativo che il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it), alla voce [“lasciare”](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI08/00000792.jpg), riporti tra gli esempi dell'uso riflessivo dell'accezione “Abbandonare la persona amata, spezzando ogni rapporto con lei. – Anche: ripudiare, divorziare”, senza annotazioni speciali:

> *Pratolini*,  3-129:  Ti  sei  lasciato  con  Marisa... Hai imboccato una bella strada, con c’è che dire.

La citazione è presa da *Il quartiere*, appunto di Vasco Pratolini.

Comment: Grazie! In più "Riflessivo (per lo più con uso reciproco)" lascia intendere che gli usi riflessivi non reciproci siano rari, ma non esclusi.

Comment: Giusta osservazione, @NicolaSap!